# How to hide or remove the bar which is top of the terminal?

Tags: shortcut-keys, vim, menu-bar

I always press <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> when I am using `vim`.
But the terminal have a help button at the top blocking me use <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> when using `vim`.

I want to hide or remove that bar. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what do you need it for, but maybe you can try Guake? It's alternative to classic terminal - you can hide whole window by pressing F12. It's also transparent, but have small bar at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using gnome-terminal? If so, go to **Edit**->**Keyboard Shortcuts**-> and uncheck **Enable menu access keys (...)**.

But I too advise you to try out the `guake` terminal. It's cool.

Comment: yeah! its work !
Thanks your advise. Guake terminal is cool !